# Are android fragments reusable?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Are android fragments reusable - i mean if i could use code like below:

```
class MyTabActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

    Fragment[] tabs = new Fragment[3];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);

        //first xml-defined fragment, it is inside  
        //FrameLayout with id R.id.loadTarget -> see openTab()
        tabs[0] = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.firstFragment);
    }

    private void openTab(int i) {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.loadTarget, getTabFragment(i));
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    private Fragment getTabFragment(int i) {
        if(tabs[i] == null) {
            switch(i) {

                //0-tab fragment has been allready 
                //retrieved in onCreate

                case 1:
                    tabs[1] = new MySecondTabFragment();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tabs[2] = new MyThirdTabFragment();
                    break;
            }
        }
        return tabs[i];
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                openTab(0);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                openTab(1);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                openTab(2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes fragments are reusable you can attach/detach a fragment to an activity several times. As you can see in the documentation after being detached the fragment is destroyed and then created again when it is added to another activity.

Comment: But if I use `replace` then it still legal to store reference for future use?

Comment: Can i achieve the same as above with `attach / detach` - if so, how? (I do not want to put in xml two remaining tab fragments until user actually clicks the corresponding tab). Can i `attach` newly created fragment in place of existing one?